# そこが+ a person + らしくはあるか meaning in this context

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions, manga, japanese-to-english

When reading ,I met with this strange expression (at my level at least). Much thanks if anyone can explain to me it's correct meaning.

Context: MC is talking with a general (A-san) ,about the plan of her Master to fight against the bandit in order to protect the town with minimum damage for both the people and her troops. The general said it's impossible given the current situation (the citizens wanted to fight but they don't have experience in battle ,and they don't have much troops left)

A「……この状況でそれは無茶だろう。
私とBだけで連中の砦に奇襲を掛ける方が、確実ではないか？」
"That plan is too far fetched given our situation now don't you think?
Wouldn't it be more safe for just me and B (another general) to launch a surprise attack on their fortress?"

MC: 「賊を倒すだけならそれでもいいんだけどさ。
この町に手を出したらまずいって思わせないと、意味がないって」
"She said (T-sama) if all we wanted to do was defeat the bandits,that would be fine.But if we don't make them think it's a bad idea to mess with this town, there's no point in doing that." (he meant that the bandit will come back to attack again)

MC:「それに町の人達もみんな戦いたいって言ってるから……
何かしらの落とし所がないと、納得してくれないだろうし」
"Also the town's people says that they're all wanted to fight so...
If we don't have some kind of a compromise, I'm sure those people will not agree to stay"
(Both MC and T-sama don't want the town's people to join with them and go attack the bandits,because worry that these citizen will die due to no combat experience ,but they're still wanted to fight)

A-san「それはそうかもしれんが……その全てを満たす策など、
そうそう思い付くものでもないだろうに」
"Maybe you're right,that could be the case but....Anyone can see it's not likely to quickly come up with such a plan, which could satisfies all of those conditions."

MC 「ですよねー」"Yeah,right~"

A-san「……とはいえ、そこがT-samaらしくはある……か」
"...That said,????" (I guess that A-san commenting about her Master kindness that trying to come up with a plan to save both the town's people and her soldier? But that just my guess based on context I'm not sure)

Comment: Related?: [「高くはある」と「高い」の違い](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19698/43676)

Comment: Do you understand if it is "そこがT-samaらしい"?

Comment: I'm only understand "That plan has T-sama's vibe/personality in it" ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider a simpler そこがT-samaらしい.

This usage of Aらしい means, as you understand, "subj. has/expresses some quality of A". More verbosely put, it means that the subject is something expected from personality or usual behavior or way of thinking of A.

そこが refers to the fact that the plan tries to fulfill many (incompatible?) objectives at the same time or T-sama tries to execute such a plan. So そこがT-samaらしい would mean that such a perfectionistic plan is something quite expected from T-sama's character / T-sama is quite likely to conceive.

Now about the ending らしくはあるか, it works as an emphasis or you can understand it as "the plan is hard, but is expected from T-sama's persoality". About か [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/77682/seemingly-non-interrogative-use-of-sentence-ending-%E3%81%8B) should be helpful. Incorporating these nuance into the above would give a precise translation.

Comment: Thank you for your analyzation .This one is very hard for me to understand ,so i will just go with something like this "That said,isn't that what T-sama is all about?"

Comment: @casualreader The translation is fine; or even simpler *that said, that is T-sama*.